# Add products with combinations to prestashop website

Tags: csv, e-commerce, prestashop

I am new to prestashop and I would like to add a list of clothes products.
I created two csv files (one for products, one for combinations) but don't add properly.

This one to import products

#

And this one to add combinations

#

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your Field separator and Multiple value separator match with CSV. We used Field separator as  ( ; ) and Multiple value separator as (,) and it worked for us

Comment: it is not problem about separator ... i can set up even in prestashop ; or ,. Prestashop recognize corectly the csv.

Answer (score 1):

Your products csv files has , and ; delimiters.
Official doc http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/CSV+Import+Parameters
There must be id for categories for example "1,2,3"
Categories can be uploaded by another file.
Please use this structure for successful upload.
"Enabled";"Name";"Categories";"Price";"Tax rule ID";"Buying price";"On sale";"Reference";"Weight";"Quantity";"Short desc.";"Long desc";"Images URL"

1;"Test";"1,2,3";130;1;75;0;"PROD-TEST";"0.500";10;"'Tis a short desc.";"This is a long description.";"http://www.myprestashop/images/product1.gif"

Combinations file csv data example

Product ID;Attribute;Value
1;Color:color:2,Size:select:1;Red:3,S:1;

Comment: to import combinations of products we have to add first the products with different ids and references?